# Selecting multiples choices in django admin filter list_filter?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-admin, admin

Currently i filter by some option in django's admin interface. For instance lets say i filter by 'By status'. Is it possible to select multiple statuses to filter results from? Here is the screenshot of the filter:

[image: http://imgur.com/tV1Nl]

Can i select multiple items from this list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the admin UI, but if you modify the URL, you can make the filtering criterion more complex.

For instance, now the URL (after you click on a filter) probably ends with something like

```
?status__exact=a
```

You can change this to

```
status__in=a%2Cm
```

in order to see both statuses `a` and `m`. The `%2C` encodes a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the following query to the URL of your list page.
in my case if i have multiple option.

```
?bookingstatus__in=booked,refunded.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the following query to the URL of your list display page

```
?my_field__gte=1&myfield__lte=10
```

for numeric fields. That way you can have a ranged selection. 
Basically you can use any query you would also use in your code.