# search_field by field choice

Tags: python, django

I've a basic django model and i was wondering is there a way to make the search fields search in the value i am mapping to instead of searching in the value saved in the database, is there a possible way that i can search by the value "Premium" ?

Model.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account')
    name =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
       (1, 'Premium'),
       (0, 'Normal'),)
    type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES)
```

Admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     search_fields = ['name','type']
    pass
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626171/django-admin-choice-field - please review and let us know?

Comment: it's not the same i guess i don't need a custom CHOICE model i just need to be able to search with the mapped values

Comment: If you use the custom choice model field, you'll be able to choose the option from a drop down box, which is more efficient than having to type the values in anyway (given that the values are fixed/static). Unless I've missed something??

Comment: my problem is not when adding or editing the record i still can use the dropdown box when adding or editing, my problem is with the search box i want to be able to search with either "Premium" or "Normal" not with 0 or 1

Comment: The search box should display the same form widget as the add/edit form, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834990/selecting-multiples-choices-in-django-admin-filter-list-filter . (is this not happening??) As you can see, the field is replaced by a drop down box which shows the choice name (i.e. Normal) instead of the integer value (i.e. 0). If you use the custom widget mentioned previously, this should just work automatically. Unless the problem is that you want a text box instead of a drop down field - although I can't think of a valid reason why this would be needed.

Comment: I do need the text box because i have many search fields and most of them has many values the drop down box wont be practical in my case
sorry i didn't get your point at first.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to set up a custom search field handler which attempts to reverse lookup the choice display field to its value. Another slight issue is that multiple values can have the same choice display name, so you'll need to take that into consideration. Here is an example of how to achieve this; https://github.com/sivaa/django-custom-search-filter/blob/master/app/admin.py . You basically have to override the queryset, perform reverse lookup, then return the correct queryset.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added the final summary as an answer, please accept or up-vote if you're happy with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from comments discussion;

You'll need to set up a custom queryset for the search filter which attempts to reverse lookup the choice display field to its value. Another slight issue is that multiple values can have the same choice display name, so you'll need to take that into consideration.

Here is an example of how to achieve this:

https://github.com/sivaa/django-custom-search-filter/blob/master/app/admin.py

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
class order(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ("Completed", "Completed"),
        ("Ordered", "Ordered"),
        ("Accepted", "Accepted"),
        ("Order Cancel", "Order Cancel"),
        ("Customer Cancel", "Customer Cancel"),
        ("Delivered", "Delivered"),
        ("Added to Cart", "Added to Cart"),
        ("Out of Delivery", "Out of Delivery"),
        ("Refund Initiated","Refund Initiated"),
        ("Return And exchange","Return And exchange"),
    )

    status = models.CharField(default="Ordered", max_length=50, null=True, choices=STATUS, blank=True)
```

View:

```
status1=request.POST.get("status")
response1=order.objects.filter(status__contains=status1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).