# How can I search the choice field using display name?

Tags: django, filter, choicefield

I want to query the item from the database using django `SmallIntegerField`. The code I used is

Here is the class defination:

```py
class Equipment(models.Model):
    asset_status = (
        (0, 'online'),
        (1, 'offline'),
        (2, 'unknown'),
        (3, 'wrong'),
        (4, 'x'),
    )
status = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=asset_status, default=0, verbose_name='Device Status')
```

The query code I used is

```py
def filter_queryset(self, qs):
    sSearch = self.request.GET.get('search[value]', None)
    print(sSearch)
    if sSearch:
        qs = qs.filter(Q(status__icontains=sSearch))
        return qs
```

I want to query this column by 'online', 'offline' and so on. Do you know how to do this?

The reference I have searched are

[Search choice field by the name in django - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054755/search-choice-field-by-the-name-in-django-python)

I also see the `Choices` API in 
https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#choices

But there is no `Q`. I am not sure whether it works. Could you please tell me about this?

And I searched for a method called `get_FOO_display`, but I don't think it can be solved. Neither did I think it can be combined with `Q`.

Thanks

Comment: In the function `filter_queryset`, is `qs` q queryset of `Equipment`?

Comment: Sorry for not giving more information and it is.

Answer (score 2):

Choices follow the format of a `actual_value_for_db, human_readable_name` tuple, where the `human_readable_name` is only for display purposes. That is, you cannot query for it as only the *first item* of the tuple is stored in the database.

If you want to make it a bit easier to find out what value you need to use you can use an enum-like declaration of the choices:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    ONLINE = 0
    OFFLINE = 1
    UNKNOWN = 2
    WRONG = 3
    X = 4

    asset_status = (
        (ONLINE, 'online'),
        (OFFLINE, 'offline'),
        (UNKNOWN, 'unknown'),
        (WRONG, 'wrong'),
        (X, 'x'),
    )
```

Then you can query for a choice by using a 'name' of the member of the `Equipment` model: `Equipment.objects.filter(status=Equipment.OFFLINE)`

It is not clear what exactly the value in your `request` is and where it comes from. I would suggest just using a `ModelForm` to ask the user for the right status type. A ModelForm should take care of the choices for that formfield and return the right type for the selected choice (which should be an integer, not a string!). Use a generic `FormView` and the rest should be a piece of cake.

Comment: And the class I should use is also ```SmallIntegerField```?

Answer (score 0):

`status` is a `SmallIntegerField` so, what you have in the database are integers. When you provide code like this:

```
asset_status = (
    (0, 'online'),
    (1, 'offline'),
    (2, 'unknown'),
    (3, 'wrong'),
    (4, 'x'),
)
```

you're telling Django: "hey, I want to be able to **display** the 0 option value  as 'online' , 1 as 'offline' ..." and so on.

So, you Django don't write such values ('online', 'offline', ...) to the database hence **you can't query on them**.

## But ...

I suppose you are having trouble getting the right integer value for the query after the user selects one of the options for filtering, you should take a look at [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield), perhaps you can use it for your filter form.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.